# How to identify a SD card when in a USB card reader

Tags: c#, windows

I have spent many hours on this and while I am close to the answer it still alludes me so I will ask those more intelligent than me for help.

I have a SD card in a card reader which I need to identify. I can the memory but I cannot say if it is an SD card or Compact flash or just USB memory. I searched and found many interesting articles but no definitive answer. I tried looking at GUIDS but that lead to a dead end as they are unique to the device but not the same for all SD cards.

Next I found an article that says look for PDCAP_D2_SUPPORTED alas I drew a blank there as I could not get that to work in c#.

Next I found in MSDN that in "Win32_PhysicalMedia class" there is a member called "uint16 MediaType" and if I get 30 from it then I have a "Memory Card". When I try to make this work it returns NULL. After typing wildly for hours trying various things I have hit the wall. To run the code below create a C# form with button = btn_get_info and richtextbox = rchtxtbx_output. You will see I can get data back from "Win32_DiskDrive" as well as "DriveInfo.GetDrives()" but very little from "Win32_PhysicalMedia".

Windows can differentiate between USB device and a SD card so I should also be able to. Any help much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

 namespace diskinfo
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

    private void btn_get_info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (di.IsReady)
            {
                if (di.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("-------------------------------------------------------\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("FreeSpace = " + di.AvailableFreeSpace + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("DriveFormat = " + di.DriveFormat + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("DriveType = " + di.DriveType + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("IsReady = " + di.IsReady + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("RootDirectory = " + di.RootDirectory + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("Name = " + di.Name + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("TotalFreeSpace = " + di.TotalFreeSpace + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("TotalSize = " + di.TotalSize + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("VolumeLabel = " + di.VolumeLabel + "\r");
                    rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r");
                }
            }
        }


        rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r\n-------------------------------------------------------\r\n");



        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1;
        searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj1 in searcher1.Get())
        {
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText(
                "\r-------------------------Win32_PhysicalMedia------------------------------\r");

            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rCapacity: " + queryObj1["Capacity"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rCaption: " + queryObj1["Caption"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rDescription: " + queryObj1["Description"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rInstallDate: " + queryObj1["InstallDate"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rName: " + queryObj1["Name"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rStatus: " + queryObj1["Status"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rCreationClassName: " + queryObj1["CreationClassName"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rManufacturer: " + queryObj1["Manufacturer"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r Model: " + queryObj1["Model"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rSKU: " + queryObj1["SKU"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rSerialNumber: " + queryObj1["SerialNumber"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rTag: " + queryObj1["Tag"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rVersion: " + queryObj1["Version"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rPartNumber: " + queryObj1["PartNumber"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rOtherIdentifyingInfo: " + queryObj1["OtherIdentifyingInfo"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rPoweredOn: " + queryObj1["PoweredOn"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rRemovable: " + queryObj1["Removable"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rReplaceable: " + queryObj1["Replaceable"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rHotSwappable: " + queryObj1["HotSwappable"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rCapacity: " + queryObj1["Capacity"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rMediaType: " + queryObj1["MediaType"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rMediaDescription: " + queryObj1["MediaDescription"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rWriteProtectOn: " + queryObj1["WriteProtectOn"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rCleanerMedia: " + queryObj1["CleanerMedia"]);


        }

        rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r\n-------------------------------------------------------\r\n");


        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;

        searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r-------------------------Win32_DiskDrive------------------------------\r");
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rSerialNumber: " + queryObj["SerialNumber"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rSignature: " + queryObj["Signature"]);
            rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\rModel: " + queryObj["Model"]);
              rchtxtbx_output.AppendText("\r");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Added

Seems that there is a difference between Logical and Physical disks. Not sure yet if this find helps me any. However I found a hidden gem inside Windows called WMIC. I tried this as follows from command line

```
wmic:root\cli>diskdrive get DeviceID,Caption,Model,Mediatype
Caption                              DeviceID            MediaType              Model
SDHC Card                            \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  Removable Media        SDHC Card
Micron 1100 SCSI Disk Device         \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  Fixed hard disk media  Micron 1100 SCSI Disk Device
Generic MassStorageClass USB Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  Removable Media        Generic MassStorageClass USB Device
```

So that does not help so I try

```
wmic:root\cli>logicaldisk get MediaType,Name
MediaType  Name
12         C:
           D:
           E:
```

I hoped to find the media type and use that but again as in the code above the OS is not giving me the MediaType.

Still cannot find how to tell if it is a SDHC card or a drive on a USB reader but the search continues.

Comment: See followng webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366217(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But why the `linq` tag?